# How to create customised popup menu design in android

Tags: android, popupmenu

I'm using android popup menu for displaying popup menu items which are getting from server side rather than static.

I need to custom design the popup menu according to the below screenshot.
[image: required design screenshot]

I'm not able to add the dotted line separator in the popup menu. Please give me some suggestions.

here is my popup menu calling code:

```
 private void popUpMethod(Context context){

        if(isMembersOnly.equalsIgnoreCase("Members Only")){
            for(int i = 0; i < MBEventsMemberOnly.size() ; i++){
                popup.getMenu().add(1, i, 1, MBEventsMemberOnly.get(i).getName());
            }
        }else {
            for(int i = 0; i < MBEventTypes.size() ; i++){
                popup.getMenu().add(1, i, 1, MBEventTypes.get(i).getName());
            }
        }


        //Inflating the Popup using xml file
        popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.members_list, popup.getMenu());

        //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                //return true;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case 0:
                        //handle menu1 click
                        break;
                    case 1:
                       //handle menu2 click
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        //handle menu3 click
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        popup.show();//showing popup menu
    }
```

Comment: Create 9 patch for popup background with arrow.

Comment: popup items are not static, they will added dynamically.. so how can i create background for that case?

Comment: 9patch image resizes itself with the view size. So no worry about dynamic size. You may find issue while setting default padding in 9patch, but after trying few images you will get how it works.

Comment: Or you may use https://android-arsenal.com/tag/146 libraries

Comment: can you please tell me how to add background for ppopup menu

Comment: and how to add dotted line separator ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191420/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-dolly-rosy).